# image map does not work on Opera and Mozilla browsers (only Google Chrome)

Tags: html, images, map

I have created a WordPress blog and inserted an image with map and some links inside, but I can't open any link by pressing on the page using any browser except Google Chrome.

This is the code:

```
<img class="aligncenter" alt="" src="http://pretesti.ge/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Untitled-2-copy.png" usemap="imgmap2013948720" align="center" />
<p style="text-align: center;">
<map id="imgmap2013948720" name="imgmap2013948720">
<area title="" alt="" coords="5,4,167,167" shape="rect" href="http://pretesti.ge/?page_id=14" target="_blank" />
<area title="" alt="" coords="174,6,336,165" shape="rect" href="http://pretesti.ge/?page_id=16" target="_blank" />
<area title="" alt="" coords="345,5,506,167" shape="rect" href="http://pretesti.ge/?page_id=18" target="_blank" />
<area title="" alt="" coords="514,5,678,169" shape="rect" href="http://pretesti.ge/?page_id=20" target="_blank" />
<!-- Created by Online Image Map Editor (http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/index) -->
</map>
</p>
```

Comment: i cant insert the code. can you help? it just wont show :(

Comment: Questions about problems with your code should be asked at StackOverflow.  They are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a hash (`#`) symbol at the start of the usemap attribute:

```
usemap="#imgmap2013948720"
```

(No need to enclose the `map` element in a `p`. The `map` element itself is non-visual.)